# What is adb command to open camera in Video capture using one particular app?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I want to be able to open camera app using adb command in video capture mode:

I am already using following command for it:

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE
```

but if more than one applications have defined that intent then it shows me "Complete action using box". I want to  avoid that box. So i wan to open that intent using one particular apk.
How can I can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the packagename and the activity name of what you want to open then you can use the below

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE -n com.packagename/com.packagename.ActivityName
```

Comment: Thanks that worked:) `adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraActivity`

Comment: Does this start the default camera on the android device.